# Login using flask and MySQL

Tags: python, bcrypt

I am setting up signup and login for my website using flask with MySQL as my database but when I try to log in it is showing the error "Incorrect username and password " even though they are both correct.

Below is the login code

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])`your text`
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Email = request.form['Email']
        Password = request.form['Password'].encode('utf-8')
        
        curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email=%s",(Email,))`your text`
        users = curl.fetchone()
        curl.close()
        
        
        if len(users) > 0:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(Password,users["Password"].encode('utf-8'))==users["Password"].encode('utf-8'):
                session['First_name']= users['First_name']
                session['Last_name']= users['Last_name']
                session['Email'] = users['Email']
                return render_template("index.html")
            else:
                return "Incorrect username or password"
        else:
            return "Error user not found"
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt has an internal comparison method, ‘bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed)‘ maybe use that instead of manually comparing the hashes.

If that don’t work make sure your password hash stored in the database is using the same hashing algorithm as the one you currently using for password hashing and than comparing.

Comment: My database password was not defined to a length of 255